# Using Intellj : Autocomplete does not work for Ethers.js 6.3.0 module

Tags: intellij-idea, ethers.js

Here is my setting.
[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLkdn.png)

cannot find any declaration about the method.
[No declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsYQ7.png)

May i know anyone facing this problem ? and what is the solution.

I also ran "Invalidate Caches / Restart".

Comment: Which IDE version do you use? What does your package.json look like?

Comment: IDE version is 2021.2.5 Ultimate version
build#IU-212.5712.43

package.json

  "dependencies": {
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "^6.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "solc": "0.8.7-fixed"
  }

Comment: It works for me in the same build. Are the packages installed? Is node_modules folder marked as a library root?